How to git mirror Bitbucket to GitHub with submodules
I want to  mirror a repo I have on Bitbucket to GitHub. However, in my Bitbucket repo I have submodules, and when they are mirrored to GitHub, they appear like non-existing folders like
https://github.com/icai-uma/MOMRISR/blob/master/dcsrn-pnorm
For that, I followed this tutorial.
How can I mirror the submodules? Should I repeat the sames steps for each submodule?
Thanks for the help.
